# Making HTML table from Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, json, go, html-table, server-sent-events

I need a constantly updating HTML table on the frontend, that gets it's data from the backend. Here is my golang backend to generate a random number, put it into a struct, then append the struct into a slice of structs, and use Server Sent Events to bring it to the frontend:

The result of this should be a long slice of a bunch of structs. I want this to be on the frontend, where the slice of structs is the entire table, and each struct in the slice is a row in a HTML Table.

```
type sliceofRand struct {
    Items []randomData
}

var sliceofRandvar sliceofRand

func formatServerSentEvent(event string, data any) (string, error) {
    m := map[string]any{
        "data": data,
    }

    buff := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})

    encoder := json.NewEncoder(buff)

    err := encoder.Encode(m)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    sb := strings.Builder{}

    sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("event: %s\n", event))
    sb.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("data: %v\n\n", buff.String()))

    return sb.String(), nil
}

func SseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "SSE not supported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Request received for price...")

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")

    priceCh := make(chan sliceofRand)

    go func() {
        for {
            number := rand.Intn(100)
            view := randomData{
                Number: number,
                Info: "Random number",
            }

            sliceofRandvar.Items = append(sliceofRandvar.Items, view)

            priceCh <- sliceofRandvar
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    for price := range priceCh {
        event, err := formatServerSentEvent("price-update", price)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }

        _, err = fmt.Fprint(w, event)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }

        flusher.Flush()
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have a function that sends data to the frontend as a Server Sent Event, and every time I generate a new random number in a seperate goroutine, I append the new struct in a list of structs, and call the SSE function and create a new SSE. Now my problem is, I get this on the frontend, and I want everything to go into a HTML table.

Here is the output I see on the frontend due to the SSE:

```
    {"data":{"Items":[{"Random_Number":14,"Something":"this_is_something"},
{"Random_Number":88,"Something":"this_is_something"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are using in the frontend; is it a framework or a simple html template ?

Let's assume you  have simple html Table :
`<table> <tbody id="rows"></tbody></table>`

You can use JQuery like this inside the JavaScript script function that gets the data :

```
var obj; //parsed from server event
/* obj = {"data":{"Items":[{"Random_Number":14,"Something":"this_is_something"},
{"Random_Number":88,"Something":"this_is_something"}]}}*/

$("#rows").empty();
obj.data.Items.forEach((element) => {

$("#rows").append("<tr><td>"+element.Random_Number+" </td><td>"+element.Something+" </td></tr>");

});
```